# How to create procedure in msql

Tags: sql

```
create procedure test
BEGIN
     select *
     from User
END
;
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this and can you show me a simple create procedure?

Comment: "msql" is not a thing, AFAIK. Do you mean "MySQL", perhaps, or "MSSQL"?

Comment: be clear on `MySQl` or `MSSQL`.

Answer (score 2):

The first link on google after typing **"create procedure in sql server"** gives your answer. Check out [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):-

```
CREATE { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ] 
    [ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }
        [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT | [READONLY]
    ] [ ,...n ]
[ WITH <procedure_option> [ ,...n ] ]
[ FOR REPLICATION ]
AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
[;]

<procedure_option> ::= 
    [ ENCRYPTION ]
    [ RECOMPILE ]
    [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
```

Comment: ...assuming the OP is interested in SQL Server.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta:- I agree..:)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with SQL Server, you've just missed `AS`:

```
create procedure test
as
BEGIN
     select *
     from User
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
    BEGIN

SELECT * FROM USER;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: This is for Mysql..

Answer (score -1):

crate procedure with parameter in SQL server
[click here sqltutorialspoint](https://www.sqltutorialspoint.com/developer/forum/143/how-to-create-procedure-with-parameter-in-sql-server)